# ThreeJs VideoTexture antialiasing/resolution

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

So I have a `VideoTexture` in ThreeJS, and it's rendering really pixelly.

The actual `pixelDensity` of the renderer is plenty, and the rest of the scene is rendering fairly crisp - I've searched high and low for some information about what to do here, but I can't find anything.

- Aniostropy settings do nothing, regardless of the number set
- Increasing `pixelDensity` to an unusually high number helps, but doesn't fix it
- The video itself is very high-definition
- I've tried using `FXAA` as a `shaderPass`, but that also didn't seem to do anything

Does anyone know how to get a crisp `VideoTexture`? Surely it's possible to get something better than the below. Is there something up with the way I'm creating the texture/material?

```
video.load()
video.play()

const texture = new VideoTexture(video)
texture.encoding = sRGBEncoding

const material = new MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: texture,
  side: FrontSide,
})

const geometry = new PlaneGeometry( 30, 17, 32 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the texture's [minification and magnification filters](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.magFilter). If you're using `NearestFilter`, it'll come out very pixellated, but you could do `LinearFilter` to get smooth interpolation in between texels:

```js
const texture = new VideoTexture(video);
texture.encoding = sRGBEncoding;
texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

Comment: do you have any other ideas? I've tried those on a screen with a DPR of 1 and it's still really jagged: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/videotexture-antialiasing-resolution-really-jagged-and-low-res/25696/7